# onitemclicklistener connected with 2 spinners

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

```
  Spinner Spte1;
  String[] path1 ={"Celsius", "Kelvin","Farenheit"};


  Spinner Spte2;
  String[] path2 ={"Celsius","Kelvin","Farenheit"};

  EditText ETTE1;
  EditText ETTE2;
```

now the second code

```
Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int position1 = Spte1.getSelectedItemPosition();
        switch (position1){

        case 0:


            break;

        case 1:

            break;
        case 2:

            break ;
            }
    }
```

but i need to make code to chose between first item in first spinner and connected with second spinner and ad number in first text then the resuslt in the second text i need the code alowe me to make this action 
appreciate .

Comment: show your layout file what you want to do exctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
    switch(parent.getId()) {
    case R.id.listview1:    
       // do something for the 1st spinner      
        break;
    case R.id.listview2:
        break;
       // do something for the 2nd spinner
    }
```